# About feval function on tutorials/2_supervised/4_train.lua

Tags: lua, torch

On gihub : 
https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/4_train.lua
we have a example of a script defining a training procedure. I'm interested by the construction of feval function in this script.

```
-- create closure to evaluate f(X) and df/dX
local feval = function(x)
      -- get new parameters
      if x ~= parameters then
         parameters:copy(x)
      end

      -- reset gradients
      gradParameters:zero()

      -- f is the average of all criterions
      local f = 0

      -- evaluate function for complete mini batch
      for i = 1,#inputs do
          -- estimate f
          local output = model:forward(inputs[i])
          local err = criterion:forward(output, targets[i])
          f = f + err

          -- estimate df/dW
          local df_do = criterion:backward(output, targets[i])
          model:backward(inputs[i], df_do)

          -- update confusion
          confusion:add(output, targets[i])
      end

      -- normalize gradients and f(X)
      gradParameters:div(#inputs)
      f = f/#inputs

      -- return f and df/dX
      return f,gradParameters
      end
```

I try to modify this function by suppressing the loop :
     for i = 1,#inputs do ...
So instead of doing the forward and backward inputs by inputs (inputs[i]) I'm doing it for the whole mini batch (inputs). This really speed up the process. This is the modify script:

```
-- create closure to evaluate f(X) and df/dX
local feval = function(x)
      -- get new parameters
      if x ~= parameters then
         parameters:copy(x)
      end

      -- reset gradients
      gradParameters:zero()

      -- f is the average of all criterions
      local f = 0
      -- evaluate function for complete mini batch

      -- estimate f
      local output = model:forward(inputs)
      local f = criterion:forward(output, targets)

      -- estimate df/dW
      local df_do = criterion:backward(output, targets)

      -- update weight  
      model:backward(inputs, df_do)

      -- update confusion
      confusion:batchAdd(output, targets) 

      -- return f and df/dX
      return f,gradParameters
      end
```

But when I check in detail the return of feval (f,gradParameters) for a given mini batch we haven't the same result with the loop and without loop.

So my questions are : 
 1 - Why do we have this loop ? 
 2 - And is it possible to get the same result without this loop ?

Regards
Sam

NB: I'm beginner in Torch7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you noticed getting the second way to work requires a bit more than simply changing feval.
In your second example, inputs needs to be a 4D tensor, rather than a table of 3D tensors (unless something has changed since I last updated). These tensors have different sizes depending on the loss criterion/model used. Whoever implemented the example must have thought the loop was an easier way to go here.  In addition, ClassNLLCriterion does not seem to like batch processing (one would usually use CrossEntropy criterion to get around this).

All of this aside though, the two methods should give the same result. The only slight difference is that the first example uses the average error/gradient, and the second uses the sum, as you can see from:

```
                   gradParameters:div(inputs:size(1))
                   f = f/inputs:size(1)
```

In the second case, f and gradParameters should differ from the first only in a factor opt.batchSize. These are mathematically equivalent for optimization purposes.

Comment: Thanks Sander for your answer. I'm agree because of the suppression of the loop we need one more dimension in the inputs. I've added CrossEntropy instead of ClassNLLCriterion it works but it doesn't change a lot the results. But I've add a other thing and it seems better the results of those two approaches  converge but I really don't understand why, it a Sequencer:   nn.Sequencer(model)

  criterion = nn.SequencerCriterion(nn.CrossEntropyCriterion(weights))

Comment: Hi Sam. I'm not sure I understand the problem. CrossEntropy should do the same as LogSoftMax + ClassNLLCriterion, but supports batch processing, so you wouldn't expect results to change.

Comment: Yes CrossEntropy doesn't change the results. But nn.Sequencer does . With nn.Sequencer order matter in inputs data and the results seems to be  close to the results obtain with the loop but I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't familiar with that module. Sorry, from your two lines of code I can't see why it would give a different result.